# Signing into Amazon login page with Android

Tags: android, jsoup, openid

I'm trying to connect to:

```
https://www.amazon.com/ap/signin?openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0&openid.assoc_handle=amzn_mturk_worker&openid.ns.pape=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fextensions%2Fpape%2F1.0&_encoding=UTF8&openid.mode=checkid_setup&openid.claimed_id=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.identity=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.pape.max_auth_age=43200&marketplaceId=A384XSLT9ODACQ&clientContext=703ea210dfe6fd07defd5ab30ac8d9&openid.return_to=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mturk.com%2Fmturk%2Fendsignin
```

I'm developing on Android using Android Studio with the jsoup library. I'm unable to post data. I'm confused on what library I should be using to work with OpenID. I'm logging into this form and pulling data off the site after login. Here is my post info:

```
appActionToken:pj2FxGfwLZT6nheliE7BMxwZrTUKEj3D
appAction:SIGNIN
clientContext:ape:NzAzZWEyMTBkZmU2ZmQwN2RlZmQ1YWIzMGFjOGQ5
openid.pape.max_auth_age:ape:NDMyMDA=
openid.return_to:ape:aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cubXR1cmsuY29tL210dXJrL2VuZHNpZ25pbg==
prevRID:ape:S1kyUFNDUkhLVFZSSjRGMjBYUUo=
openid.identity:ape:aHR0cDovL3NwZWNzLm9wZW5pZC5uZXQvYXV0aC8yLjAvaWRlbnRpZmllcl9zZWxlY3Q=
openid.assoc_handle:ape:YW16bl9tdHVya193b3JrZXI=
openid.mode:ape:Y2hlY2tpZF9zZXR1cA==
openid.ns.pape:ape:aHR0cDovL3NwZWNzLm9wZW5pZC5uZXQvZXh0ZW5zaW9ucy9wYXBlLzEuMA==
openid.claimed_id:ape:aHR0cDovL3NwZWNzLm9wZW5pZC5uZXQvYXV0aC8yLjAvaWRlbnRpZmllcl9zZWxlY3Q=
pageId:ape:YW16bl9tdHVya193b3JrZXI=
openid.ns:ape:aHR0cDovL3NwZWNzLm9wZW5pZC5uZXQvYXV0aC8yLjA=
email: -Deleted-
create:0
password: -Deleted-
metadata1: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
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "I'm unable to post data" ? What is not working, and how is it not working ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jsoup won't help here because it doesn't parse Javascript. The site you're targetting makes heavy use of Javascript.

Instead, I suggest you to use a tool like [ui4j](https://github.com/ui4j/ui4j) or [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org).